# Find a symmetric random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$ that is transient.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I wanted to know if it is possible find a symmetric random walk on $Z$ that is not recurrent. Let $X$ have the following distribution, with a probability $1/2^{i+1}$, $X=\pm b_i$.

Let $$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n X_k$$
be the random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$ with $X_k$ having the same distribution as $X$. The problem is to find $b_n$ such that $S_n$ is transient.

We need to find $b_n$ large enough so that $E(X)$ is not defined (otherwise it would be 0 by symmetry and thus recurrent). I think $b_n=2^n$ is sufficient, but am having trouble showing transience.

We know that a random walk is transient iff $$\int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{1}{1-\varphi_X(t)}dt<\infty$$

I computed the characteristic function of $X$ as follows:

$$\varphi_X(t)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}e^{it2^n}+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}e^{it2^{-n}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(t2^n)}{2^n}$$

But I am unsure of how to proceed.

Comment: $b_n=2^n$ is certainly large enough that the expectation is undefined. What tools/criteria do you have to establish transience?

Comment: We have all the standard tools at our disposal including greens functions and characteristic functions.

Comment: I have added my current attempt.

Comment: It seems that $\varphi_X(t)$ is close to linear near the origin: can be bounded by 1-2|t| and 1-3|t|. So, the integral in the $\epsilon$ neighborhood of 0 is $\infty$...

Comment: Where to find this integral involving the characteristic function criteria for transience? Please, someone send me references... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. $\varphi_X(t)$ is periodic (with period $\pi/2$). So, we may consider a small neighborhood around zero, say $(-\delta,\delta)$
2. As I mentioned in the comments $b_n=2^n$ is not enough to get transience. So, let $b_n=4^n$
3. For $t\in(-\delta,\delta)$ and some constant $c$

$$1-\varphi_X(t)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1-\cos(t4^n)}{2^n}\ge c\sqrt{|t|}$$

4. Finally,

$$\int_{-\delta}^\delta \frac{1}{1-\varphi_X(t)}dt\le \int_{-\delta}^\delta \frac{1}{c\sqrt{|t|}}dt<\infty$$

So, the random walk is transient.